# Iframe load callback is called multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I Have a simple web page and I have a following script.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function sendTraffic(typeOfTraffic){
        var ipAddr = document.getElementById("serverIpaddr").value;
        //alert(ipAddr);
        $("#WAFTest").attr("src", '/cgi-bin/test.py?wat='+typeOfTraffic+'&ipaddr='+ipAddr);
        $("#WAFTest").load(function () {
            alert("Test done");
        });
    }
    </script>
```

I have a button and this function sendTraffic is called. What I am seeing is  Test done alert comes up once for the first time , twice for the second time and thrice for the third time and it keeps going on.

```
<button type="button" id="btnSendPing" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="sendTraffic('sendping')">Send Ping Traffic</button>
```

I am not able to figure out what wrong I am doing. I am using twitter bootstrap just FYI.

EDIT:
I am using chrome on Mac. #WAFTest is an Iframe. I am just trying to get data from the server and load it to the Iframe.

Comment: That usually means an event handler is bound inside another event handler, but the posted code doesn't seem to have such issues, as there's an inline event handler being used. As such, something important is probably missing from the posted code.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Just a guess, but it might relate to event bubbling

Comment: And what is `WAFTest`, and why would it have a `src` and a load event, and why would that load event be called etc ?

Comment: shouldn't the AJAX `.load()` have *url* as first parameter? I guess it might be recognised by jQuery as a normal `load` event - http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: I see, AJAX tag was a mistake :)

Comment: @phillip100 : I tried to pass URL to load but it doesn't load the data. So I did the same thing with div and it works fine. I am not sure why its like this. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Like the others said, your `.load()` event should have been registered **only once**.

If solution posted in other answers doesn't work for you (although it should), there's another way to go

[**`.one()`**](http://api.jquery.com/one/) :

> Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most **once** per element per event type

```
function sendTraffic(typeOfTraffic){
    var ipAddr = document.getElementById("serverIpaddr").value;
    //alert(ipAddr);
    $("#WAFTest").attr("src", '/cgi-bin/test.py?wat='+typeOfTraffic+'&ipaddr='+ipAddr);
    $("#WAFTest").one('load', function () {
        alert("Test done");
    });
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/znrkqcxf/)

---

Althought solution posted in other answers is more proper. I would however remove `onclick` attribute and set click event handler for the element using jQuery.

To avoid ambiguities (as `.load()` is also a method used for AJAX request), I'd recommend use `.on()` to bind the `load` event handler

```
<iframe id="WAFTest"></iframe>
<button type="button" data-ping="sendping" class="btnSendPing btn btn-primary btn-lg">Send Ping Traffic</button>
<input id="serverIpaddr" value="something" />
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.btnSendPing').click(function(){
        var ipAddr = $("#serverIpaddr").val();
        var typeOfTraffic = $(this).data('ping');
        $("#WAFTest").attr("src", '/cgi-bin/test.py?wat='+typeOfTraffic+'&ipaddr='+ipAddr);
    });

    $("#WAFTest").on('load', function () {
        alert("Test done");
    });

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4s9vn836/)

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you call `sendTraffic()` you bind a new instance of the event handler, which explains the behavior you describe: the first time you call it you attach a `load` event handler, then the `iframe` loads and the event fires. The second time you call the function, you bind **another** copy of the event handler to the `load` event, so both handlers execute the next time the `iframe` loads.

The solution is pretty simple: just take the event binding outside `sendTraffic()`:

```
<script>
  function sendTraffic(typeOfTraffic) {
    var ipAddr = document.getElementById("serverIpaddr").value;
    //alert(ipAddr);
    $("#WAFTest").attr("src", '/cgi-bin/test.py?wat='+typeOfTraffic+'&ipaddr='+ipAddr);
  }
  $("#WAFTest").load(function() {
    alert("Test done");
  });
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried this, data loads fine but alert is not happening. :/

Comment: What you want me to try ? I tried your suggestion but Test done alert is not happening.

Comment: Is jQuery loaded by the time the <script> in question is executed? Try adding alert($.fn.jquery); just before the $("#WAFTest").load(...) piece.

Comment: Yes its giving me the alert with 1.11.2.

Comment: And the <iframe> you are referring to appears in the HTML before the script? The script needs to be executed after the iframe is parsed into the DOM.

Comment: I think that might be the case.  I am think I will just use div. Its working fine with div.

Comment: It is good practice to locate all your scripts at the very end of the page, just before the closing </body> tag, and have any DOM-related code execute after page load, as explained here: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 0):

With every call of

```
$("#WAFTest").load(function () {
    alert("Test done");
});
```

you are binding a new Event-Listener to the load event of the iframe.

You have to put the call outside of the function, so it is only called and binded once.

**Edit:**

To prevent a failure of the code, when the DOM is not ready when the code-snippet is called, you have to wrap it in the `ready` function of jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#WAFTest").load(function () {
        alert("Test done");
    });
})
```

Comment: I tried this, data loads fine but alert is not happening