# iframe apears two times in different manners

Tags: php, html, ajax, iframe, load

I need to refresh my website every second, in order to show the changes.

So I had following code:

```
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper" id="refresh">
    <div class="col_3">
    </div>

    <div class="col_3">

      <?php 
                echo '<h1 style="text-align: center;">Das Ventil ist  '.$row['statusText'].'</h1>';
                echo '<h1 style="text-align: center;">Die Zeit seitdem das Ventil '.$row['statusText'].' ist = '.secondsToTime($elapsed).'</h1>';?>

      <div class="col_3">
      </div>

      <div class="col_3" style="text-align: center;">
        <form action="index.php" method="post" id="LED" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input id="submit_button" type="submit" name="toggle_LED" value="Ventil" />
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function() {
            var updater = setTimeout(function() {
              $('div#refresh').load('index.php', 'update=true');
            }, 1000);
          });
        </script>
        <br>
        <br>


      </div>

      <div class="col_3">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col_3">
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>

<html>
<div style="text-align: center;" id="charts">

  <form>

    <iframe width="450" height="260" style="border: 1px solid #cccccc;" src="https://thingspeak.com/channels/102503/charts/1?bgcolor=%23ffffff&color=%23d62020&dynamic=true&results=40&title=LightRaw&type=line"></iframe>
  </form>
</div>

</html>

</html>
```

The problem is that I need to have an iframe in the same page which I don't want it to be refreshed (every second).

I added it in a seperate div with a different ID but it is shown up two time in the page: once top right whith refreshing and once in the middle without refreshing.

The second one is what I realy need.

I did read this link and tried it. But it was too complicated for my case.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28919822/iframe-load-callback-is-called-multiple-times](https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/28919822/iframe-load-callback-is-called-multiple-times)

Comment: yuo can't have multiple `<html>` and `<body>` on the same page.

Comment: I don't have multiple <body>
But multiple <html>
I don't think that is the problem. I edited it and nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Use a refresh header in the page that is in the iframe.

`iframe` tag in main page

```
<iframe src="page-with-refreshes.html"></iframe>
```

**page-with-refreshes.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Title</title>
   <!-- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh -->
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
</head>
<body>
  ... page content here ...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand; header in the page that is in the iframe?!
I have already a refresher with .load every 1000 ms.

Could you please give more details?

Comment: If you put the header in the page in the iframe, you don't need the `.load`. The browser will request the updates.

Comment: but it doesn't refresh every second anymore. The page refreshes every 5s now!
And all the page refreshes now every 5s.

You are right, it the frame doesn't apear two times. But I need to have the time to be refreshed every second and the frame doesn't refresh with it.

Comment: You can change the 5 to a 1

Comment: then it will be the same as .load and all the page will refresh every second.

What I need is to divide the part with time from the part with iframe. I need to have the part with time refreshed every second and the part with iframe every min